# I make a noise but make no sound

Tags: riddle, rhyme

> I make a noise but make no sound,
>   I am in the air and on the ground,
>   I am bigger than a city but smaller than a town.

**What am I?**

Comment: Welcome to Puzzling! This is very likely to be closed as "too broad" or "low quality" - I suggest adding more information and punctuation.

Comment: title is not the question body, please edit it.

Answer (score 1):

Are you an

> EMI (Electro Magnetic Interface)

Explanation

I make a noise but make no sound,

> EMI causes noise in signals. EMI don't make any sound.

I am in the air and on the ground,

> EMI can be present on both air and ground.

I am bigger than a city but smaller than a town

> High electri'city' can cause EMI

---

Another guess if it's a wordplay.

Are you

> **Er** ([Er](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/er))

I make a noise but make no sound,

> **i** or **e**, since only those two letters are present in noise, but not in sound

I am in the air and on the ground,

> **r**, since r is the only letter present in both air and ground

I am bigger than a city but smaller than a town

> bigg**er** and small**er**, both has **er**

Comment: _bigger than city, smaller than town_ this might be alphabetical order.

Answer (score 0):

You are

> Nothing.
>  Nothing meets the criteria as given.

Comment: Nothing doesn't really make a noise though

Comment: "Nothing makes a noise but makes no sound" would be correct under the assumption that there really *is* nothing that fits the criteria, wich i don't believe.